# Clone Colorbox Image Link with JQuery

Tags: 7, javascript

I need to clone a colorbox image link (the first of all colorbox links on the loaded page) and add it onto a div-tag. how could I do that with javascript/jquery? thnx!

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
        $('#main-stuff').append('<div id="bgImgOverlay"></div>').css("cursor","pointer");
        $('#bgImgOverlay').click(function() {
            $("a[rel='gallery-all']").colorbox({open:true});
         });
```

Comment: This does not clone a link, so either the question is not clear on what you want or this answer is not correct.